# How to add attribute 'alt' to react core UI CAvatar component?

Tags: avatar, core-ui, alt-attribute

Ho to add **alt** attribute for the React coreUI CAvatar img?

We have the below code to display the image as an avatar in our application, but while doing the web accessibility test we get a **Missing alternative text** error for this image.

```
<CAvatar style={{backgroundColor:"#71c6a2"}} src='/assets/img/avatars/power.jpg' size="lg" />
```

So I tried to add alt text like below
`<CAvatar style={{backgroundColor:"#71c6a2"}} src='/assets/img/avatars/power.jpg' size="lg" alt="power" />`
but the alt text is applied for the outside div of the avatar.
***How to add alt text for img attribute when using CAvatar?***
here is the generated HTML for ref: `<div class="avatar avatar-lg" alt="Yet-to-Start" style="background-color: rgb(113, 198, 162);"><img src="/assets/img/avatars/power.jpg" class="avatar-img"></div>`